# Warning: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry point and does not have an identifier for runtime access.Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, warnings, uistoryboard

I did some searches about this warning. I am pretty sure I have all the storyboard ID in all view controllers and I did select an initial controller. But, the warning is still here. The only thing I am still wondering is do I also need to set the storyboard ID for navigation controller? If this is not a case, any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Just restart xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I think you did not select the initial ViewController. Go to your active storyboard, choose your initial ViewController then click on the attribute inspector on the top right corner of Xcode then click on the "In Initial View Controller" marker. For more check the image[image]